# MemoryError from numpy.linalg.svd for large matrices

Tags: python, numpy, svd

The following command will fail on my machine, with Windows 7 ultimate SP1 x64, Python 3.3.3 x64, numpy 1.8.0, and 16GB memory, which seems sufficient for the task. And it also fails on a cluster.

```
python -c "import numpy as np;np.linalg.svd(np.random.random((25000,10000)))"
```

Any ideas about the reason? Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to have at least 3 contiguous chunks of RAM of ~2 GB each, and the SVD also needs a rather big amount of intermediate memory. I'd try `scipy.sparse.svds`, which is slower for dense matrices but uses [much less memory](http://fa.bianp.net/blog/2012/singular-value-decomposition-in-scipy/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are just hitting a limit of your RAM: I run this on my Linux box (64Gb of RAM) and the process occupies 14.4 Gb. If you have a 16Gb machine then some of it is occupied by OS and other stuff, so perhaps you just miss a bit of spare RAM for the process.

Comment: I updated my question. Actually it also fails on a cluster with enough memory, which gave a "segmentation fault". Our IT guy commented that "The segmentation fault occurs in the main loop of python interpreter where
bytecode is evaluated and executed. It's strange how deep the problem is and it's difficult to debug without good knowledge of the CPython virtual machine." Interestingly, the `scipy.linalg.svd` works quite well so far. What is the memory occupation of Python in your case, if using `scipy.linalg.svd`?

Comment: But it's still hard to explain that why it fails on a cluster

Comment: Certainly, with the amount of details you've given us it is very hard.

Comment: Anyway it's OK with scipy.linalg.svd

Answer (score 1):

My thought would be you have insufficient resources available.
This ran on my Mac Mini with 16GB of RAM.  Python peaked at 8.5GB and my swapfile grew to almost 15GB during processing.

What is the size of your swapfile and is it dynamic or preallocated?  I would consider bumping it to 32GB, preallocated, if you have disk available.

Comment: But it's hard to explain that it also fails on the cluster.